# Using Regex to split a text string every pattern occurence and then within the match

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to take some text in the form:

```
ONLINE TRANSACTION 
PERSON2 , MAILBOXES , VIA ONLINE - PYMT , FP 03/04/21 10 , 34130520496279000N

306.00 
ONLINE TRANSACTION 
PERSON3 , COM BULDING 1391 , VIA ONLINE - PYMT , FP 10/04/21 10 , 59190636993136000N

7,200.00 
AUTOMATED CREDIT 
PERSON4 , GLEN 14 , FP 18/04/21 2028 , 
00151146632BBHGBLK
1,675.00 

ONLINE TRANSACTION 
A COMPANY , INS , VIA ONLINE - PYMT , FP 17/04/21 10 , 13221513368328000N

673.36
```

The data has been derived from a PDF, via google docs and `getTables` so there are some random whitespace and new line chars in there which help to split each entry into what is in effect 4 elements:

```
TRANSACTION TYPE
PAYEE/CREDITOR
PAID IN
PAID OUT
```

Ideally I want to return a 2d array of each entry with each sub array split for each of the above elements

The regex I've come up with is `/(.*)\s\n([\w\W]*?)\n(\n|[0-9,]+\.\d{2}\s\n)(\n|[0-9,]+\.\d{2})/g` and seems to work fine using `regex101.com` but I can't figure out what to use in javascript to get the result. I've tried using `split` & `match` but only seem to get one result and thats not split up.

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT1: Getting somewhere with this:

```
let regEx = /([^\s].*)\s\n([\w\W]*?)\n(\n|[0-9,]+\.\d{2}\s\n)(\n|[0-9,]+\.\d{2})/g;

let result = tableText.match(regEx)

let entries = result.map(result => {let retRes = result.split(regEx); retRes.pop(); retRes.shift(); return retRes;} );
```

Not entirely sure why I'm getting back a 6 element array (hence the `pop` and `shift`)

Comment: I just copied and pasted the text you posted into the console wrapped by backticks and then ran the code you provided minus the last line, and I get `result` as an array of 4 items. Maybe your input `tableText` is different from what you have posted?

Comment: Hmm. Yep I wondering if there are some sneaky special chars in there.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a small sample for `tavleText` that would reproduce the problem?